# Symfony2 Entity form type with a specific query_buider

Tags: symfony-2.1, symfony-forms

**Context**

In my case, I've some orders with "discount vouchers" (discount). A discount can be use on under different conditions. For instance, discounts have an expired date, can be used by a limited number of customers, can be dedicated to a user, ...

Each discount can be attached to several order.

In my backoffice, I want to add to order create form a field "Discount" with a list of discount available but only right discounts.

**What I made**

- An entity "order" with a field manyToMany

  ```
  /**
  * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="PATH\MyBundle\Entity\Discount", inversedBy="orders")
   * @ORM\JoinTable(name="shop_discounts_orders",
   *      joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="order_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
   *      inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="discount_id", referencedColumnName="id")}
   *      )
   */
  private $discounts;
  ```
- An entity "discounts" with a field manyToMany

  ```
   /**
   * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="PATH\MyBundle\Entity\Order", mappedBy="discounts")
   */
   private $orders;
  ```
- A form OrderType with a field discounts

  ```
  $builder->add('discounts', 'entity',
      array( 'label' => 'Discount vouchers',
          'required' => false,
          'expanded' => true,
          'class' => 'PATH\MyBundle\Entity\Discount',
          'property' => 'title',
          'multiple' => true,
          'query_builder' => function(EntityRepository $er) use ($params) {
                      return $er->getQuerySelectType($params);
                  },
      ));
  ```

With this solution, I can return specific discount defined by my request in my entity repository. It's good for expired date condition for instance.

**What I would like**

I'd like to filter results in the checkbox list. In fact, I want limit usage of the discount to a dedicated user, limit to a list of products, or limit the number of usage... And these condition cannot be done by a simple sql request.

I try to create special Type. My idea is to have an array of entities Discount and load a choice list... After that, I create a dataTransformer but It doesn't work !

Thank's for your ideas !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution and explain it if someone have the same issue as me.

- Create a custom Type

My custom type is inspired by Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Form\Type\DoctrineType

```
class DiscountOrderType extends AbstractType
{
     // overide choiceList callback
     public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
     {
        $choiceListCache =& $this->choiceListCache;
        $type = $this;

        $choiceList = function (Options $options) use (&$choiceListCache, &$time, $container) {

          [[ Copy paste same as Doctrine type ]]
        // Create your own choiceList class (EntityChoiceList)
        if (!isset($choiceListCache[$hash])) {
            $choiceListCache[$hash] = new DiscountChoiceList(
                $options['em'],
                $options['class'],
                $options['property'],
                $options['loader'],
                $options['choices'],
                $options['group_by']
            );
            // If you want add container
            $choiceListCache[$hash]->setContainer($container);
        }

        return $choiceListCache[$hash];
    };

    $resolver->setDefaults(array(
        'choice_list'       => $choiceList,
    ));

}
```

- Create a custom EntityChoiceList

My custom type is inspired by Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Form\ChoiceList\EntityChoiceList

```
class EntityChoiceList extends ObjectChoiceList
{
protected function load()
{
    if ($this->entityLoader) {
        $entities = $this->entityLoader->getEntities();
    } else {
        $entities = $this->em->getRepository($this->class)->findAll();
    }

    // You have access to the entities in the choice list
    // Add your custom code here to manipulate the choice list
    // you can do some check not properly possible with sql request (http requests on each result, ...) before add it in choice list
    // you can add some custom cache rules, ...
    // if you use gedmon and want apply a "join" with translate table, you can add $query->setHint(\Doctrine\ORM\Query::HINT_CUSTOM_OUTPUT_WALKER, 'Gedmo\\Translatable\\Query\\TreeWalker\\TranslationWalker'); before playing request...
    // Possibilities are infinite

    // FOR INSTANCE : you already want unset first entity of the result
    if (isset($entities[0])) {
        unset($entities[0]);
    }
    // END OF CUSTOM CODE
    try {
        // The second parameter $labels is ignored by ObjectChoiceList
        // The third parameter $preferredChoices is currently not supported
        parent::initialize($entities, array(), array());
    } catch (StringCastException $e) {
        throw new StringCastException(str_replace('argument $labelPath', 'option "property"', $e->getMessage()), null, $e);
    }

    $this->loaded = true;
}
```

Of course you can try to extend symfony class for beautyfull code ;).

Thank's to @maxwell2022 for your help !

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `$options` from `public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)` to pass your `user` and `product` for instance. With those 2 informations you could refine your list of discount (in your query)

if you do so you need to add them in the setDefaultValue

```
public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
{
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'user_discount' => null,
            'product_discount' => null,
        ));
}
```

and in your controller:

```
$form = $this->formFactory->create(new YourFormType(), $entity, array(
    'user_discount' => $this->getUser(),
    'product_discount' => $product,
));
```

Comment: It's not what I want. I've no problem to access to the data. I would like create an array in PHP of entities composed with several SQL requests (query_builder param use createQueryBuilder...). My select box (or check box) will be build with this array.

Comment: Sorry, I've read again but I don't understand what do you mean by "I'd like to filter results in the checkbox list."

Comment: I don't want all results return by the sql request. I want to check data with a PHP script (and remove none corresponding resusts) for each discount entity before building the view of checkboxes. With 'query_builder' you can only filter with a SQL request

Comment: Is it impossible for you to build a query that is doing the same job than your PHP script? I don't think there is any options that allow second filtering on the collection. what you could do is a twig function to check each one of them and display it or not.

Comment: It's not possible just because that's I don't want. You can see my solution.